# Variáveis compartilhadas não atualizam após requisição http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Criei um Service para poder compartilhar uma variável com a minha aplicação inteira, porém o valor não está sendo atualizado:

- O service faz apenas uma consulta no servidor para retornar o numero de usuários pendentes
- E eu gostaria que este valor fosse compartilhado em diversos locais da aplicação, neste caso eu estou mostrando como seria com o header, que ele mostra um contador de usuários pendentes
- Após a consulta, o valor retornado está correto e eu dou um console.log na variavel "service.pendingUsersCount" e o valor está correto, mas na view ele permanece o mesmo

```js
// MEU SERVICE
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('meuModulo')
        .factory('UserPendingService', UserPendingService);

    UserPendingService.$inject = [
        'UserService',
        'Restangular'
    ];
    function UserPendingService(UserService,
                                Restangular) {

    var service = {};

    service.pendingUsersCount = 2;

    _activate();

    return service;

        function _activate() {
            UserService.searchPendingUsers()
                       .then(_successFn, _errorFn);

            function _successFn(response) {
                service.pendingUsersCount = response.data.count;
                // O valor é imprimido corretamente, porém a variavel "pendingUsersCount" não é atualizada na view
                console.log(service.pendingUsersCount); 
            }

            function _errorFn(response) {

            }
        }
    }
})();


// UM DOS LOCAIS DA APLICAÇAO A ONDE ESTE SERVICE É UTILIZADO
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('meuModulo')
        .directive('headerNotification', headerNotification)
        .controller('HeaderNotificationController', HeaderNotificationController);

    headerNotification.$inject = [
        'APP_PATH'
    ];
    function headerNotification(APP_PATH) {
        return {
            templateUrl:      'header-notification.view.html',
            restrict:         'E',
            replace:          true,
            controller:       HeaderNotificationController,
            controllerAs:     'headerNotificationCtrl',
            bindToController: true,
        }
    }

    HeaderNotificationController.$inject = [
        'UserPendingService'
    ];
    function HeaderNotificationController(UserPendingService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.models = {
            usersCount: UserPendingService.pendingUsersCount
        };
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito provavelmente o seu erro seja porque você está usando uma variavel para referenciar o seu controller e deste modo o controller não é notificado do update. Para resolver o problema voce pode user o `$scope` de entrada na função, se ainda assim nao resolver voce pode forçar o Angular através do `$apply` a fazer um `$digest` no seu modelo:

Ou atualizar o seu modelo dentro de uma chamada de `$scope.$apply(function(){...})`

Tente:

```
function HeaderNotificationController(UserPendingService, $scope) {
    $scope.models.usersCount = UserPendingService.pendingUsersCount;
}
```

Ou:

```
function HeaderNotificationController(UserPendingService, $scope) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
         $scope.models = {
                usersCount: UserPendingService.pendingUsersCount
          };
    });
}
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, o $scope.$apply funcionou, agora estou vendo como eu posso fazer isso utilizando o "controllerAs", muuito obrigado